# Creating a smaller replica of a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a div full of text, photos, etc. It is generated dynamically, and usually around 10:1 ratio height:width.

I want to create a replica of this div on the same page, but making it 1/8 of the width.

EDIT: All of the contents should also be at 1/8 scale.

This thin tall overview div doesn't need to be able to be interacted with, just accurately show the contents of the other larger div.

Any Ideas how I would/should do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about a thumbnail?  So, the image, and the text, should be 1/8 the size?  I don't know how to accomplish that, I'm just asking to make sure I understand.

Comment: Yes, everything should be at 1/8 scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an idea, you may try out the `-webkit-transform` and other such css styles on a jQuery `.clone()` of your larger div. Like,

```
$('#theDiv').clone().css('-webkit-transform', 'scale(.125, .125)');
```

Not sure if that would work, but its an idea :)

**Edit** I know this might not work on all browsers out there, but it will save you the trouble of resizing all the child elements, I believe.

Comment: @mu: sorry, I didn't get you?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the jQuery clone() method to make the copy and css() method to change the width.

```
  var w = $("#thediv").width();
  var clone = $('#thediv').clone().css("width", w/8);
```

Then you can use the append() method to place this clone into some new position on your page. Note however, that the new width will depend on the content of the div that you are cloning. So you may have to set the overflow and so on to make sure it works properly.

Comment: Would I probably need to create another set of css with all of the inner contents (text/images/divs) properties (height/width/size) divided by 8 if I wanted it to look correct?

Comment: @float Sounds about right. use addClass() to add a css class to the cloned div and have all the definitions for the new class in your css file. Since its dynamic if you need to be specific about some dimensions you will have to do it programatically though.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head,

```
$origDiv = $('#originaldiv');
$cloneDiv = $origDiv.clone(true);
```

Then set all the individual size-sensitive properties of $cloneDiv to 1/8 that of the original. Do things like iterating over the images to calculate their new height/width.

It's insane to do this with jQuery though, do as much as you can with HTML and CSS and use jQuery for the more dynamic elements.